# I get this value always null

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I have this method in my backing bean, when the user click the bottom this method will be called in order to get the values and update these value in the DB.

```
public String doApproverActionSendForAwardTeam() {
IIMDelegate iimDelegate = new IIMDelegate();
try {
if (isUpdateMode) {
addIdeaDto.setIdeaId(hiddenIdeaId);
addIdeaDto.setSendForAwardNotes(addIdeaDto.getSendForAwardNotes());
addIdeaDto.setStatusCode(7);
if (addIdeaDto.getSendForAwardNotes() == null) {
addInformationMessage("enter the note...");
return null;

}                           
iimDelegate.approverActionSendForAwardTeam(addIdeaDto);
addPointForApprover();
addInformationMessage(" Done ...");
return "goSearchIdeasApproverUI";
}
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 addErrorMessage(" Error...");
}
 return null;
 }
```

The problem is when i click the bottom if the input text is empty the message show  in order to enter the value and after I enter the value is stay same the message it show  and show  , it mean that there is no value for this input and the method not complete the execution.

I make sure that the value bind right but I do not know why its happend like that, it is not first time to use the information message.

this is the jsp page:

```
<tr>
<td><rich:panel>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value=" send idea "></h:outputText>
</f:facet>
<table>
<tr>                                                                                
<td>                                                                                        
<table>                                                                                               
<tr>                                                                                                     
<td width="80px" align="left"><h:outputLabel                                                                                                                   
value="note"></h:outputLabel></td>
<td width="5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td><h:inputText id="notesId3" maxlength="100" style="width:700px"
value="#{ideaDetailsBean.addIdeaDto.sendForAwardNotes}"></h:inputText> 
</td>                                                                                           
</tr>                                                                                 
</table>                                                                            
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</rich:panel></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%" align="center">
<table>
<td width="3px"><h:commandButton image="6.png" immediate="true"
action="#{ideaDetailsBean.doApproverActionSendForAwardTeam}">                                                                          
</h:commandButton></td>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

addIdeaDto class:

```
public class AddIdeaDto {

private Long ideaId;
private Integer statusCode;
private String sendForAwardNotes;
public Long getIdeaId() {
return ideaId;
}
public void setIdeaId(Long ideaId) {
this.ideaId = ideaId;
}
 public Integer getStatusCode() {
 return statusCode;
 }
 public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
 this.statusCode = statusCode;
 }
 public String getSendForAwardNotes() {
 return sendForAwardNotes;
 }
 public void setSendForAwardNotes(String sendForAwardNotes) {
 this.sendForAwardNotes = sendForAwardNotes;
 }
 }
```

it stay in this if, it mean the value of it is always null

```
if (addIdeaDto.getSendForAwardNotes() == null) {
addInformationMessage("enter the note...");
return null;}
```

only it show the information message even if I enter the value, and notes that I did not use SendForAwardNotes anywhere before this method

Comment: Please add the context too, e.g. where does it get `addIdeaDto` from etc. Also, `addIdeaDto.setSendForAwardNotes(addIdeaDto.getSendForAwardNotes());` is redundant.

Comment: @GhostCat I update my code

Comment: @GhostCat  I update my code

Comment: @ Darshan Mehta what do you mean by redundant?

Comment: I find the problem from this addIdeaDto.getSendForAwardNotes() == null that why it returns to me null.. who i can solve it, acutely this value coming from the jsp page??